# javascript text validation not working. alert message doesn't show

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I have a simple form validation script:

```
<script language=”javascript”>
    function return validate_form(register)
 {      
if (""==document.forms.register.FNAME.value){
    alert("This field is required!");
    document.forms.register.FNAME.focus();
    return false;
}    
if (""==document.forms.register.LNAME.value){
    alert("This field is required!");
    document.forms.register.LNAME.focus();
    return false;
}
if (EMAIL.value.search( /^[a-zA-Z]+([_\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([\.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/ ) == -1){
    alert(“Wrong email”);
    return false;
}       
if('0'==document.forms.register.GENDER.value){
    alert("You must select an option!");
    document.forms.register.GENDER.focus();
    return false;
}
if (""==document.forms.register.ADDRESS.value){
    alert("This field is required!");
    document.forms.register.ADDRESS.focus();
    return false;
}
if (""==document.forms.register.CONTACTNO.value){
    alert("This field is required!");
    document.forms.register.CONTACTNO.focus();
    return false;
}
}
</script>
```

the function is called using the onSubmit handler, but nothing happens when submit is clicked. It goes directly to the PHP script instead of javascript 'intercepting' it. Any thoughts?

Form HTML:

```
 <form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_form(register);">
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tr>
  <td width="46%" height="24" align="right">First Name:</td>
  <td width="54%"><input name="FNAME" type="text" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Last Name:</td>
  <td><input name="LNAME" type="text" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Email Address</td>
  <td><input name="EMAIL" type="text" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Gender:</td>
  <td><select name="GENDER">
      <option value="" selected="selected">- Select One -</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Address:</td>
  <td><input name="ADDRESS" type="text" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Contact No.:</td>
  <td><input name="CONTACTNO" type="text" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Password</td>
  <td><input name="PASSWORD" type="password" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td height="24" align="right">Re-type Password</td>
  <td><input name="PASSWORD2" type="password" size"20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
```

the alert message doesn't show? what is wrong??

Comment: Also, just so you are aware, this code is very old fashioned. There are much less painful ways to do this. Using CSS instead of table would help ease the pain of development for you. Also, you have a bunch of Yoda conditions. Developers generally prefer them to be something like if(variableName == "someValue") rather than if("someValue" == variableName)

Comment: PLEASE remove the arguments here - dot notation will pick up the form name. you do not need to pass around this argument ever. it might actually screw with your script.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I refactored your code a bit to make more sense and maintainability

html change:

```
<form name="register" action="register.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_form();">
```

Sample JS:

```
function validate_form() {
    var frm = document.forms.register;
    function focus_and_false(el) {
        el.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if( frm.FNAME.value === "" ) { /* repeat this for all form elements you want to validate */
        alert("This field is required!");
        return focus_and_false(frm.FNAME); /* this is not the best, but i'm showing you how you can reduce overall code by not rewriting the same things. */
    }
    return true;
}​
```

[and here is a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/GV7WL/)

Comment: then the issues are other places, my fiddle works. Try to reproduce the error in jsFiddle and I might be able to help further.

Comment: yes. i tried your fiddle it did work. there aren't any error message just that the alert still won't show. :\ thank you for you're help. i'll be trying to re code and use you're code.

Comment: I think the main issues were your yoda conditions ?? and that you were mucking around with the variable register when it was already being used in the dot notation...

Answer (score 1):

You have a HUGE syntax error in your javascript ...

```
function return validate_form(register)
```

should be

```
function validate_form(register)
```

Maybe you can start with that :)

And add an alert just after the function starts so you know that when you call it, it actually executes or at least tries to.

Another syntax error:

```
<script language=”javascript”>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

And finally i would change the function name to

```
function validateForm(register)
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: thank for mentioning. i already changed it but the alert message is still not showing. i'm still new in using javascript so i thought this code was the simplest. but can't seem to make it work?

Comment: what does renaming the function to use camelCase vs underscore have to do with anything ?

Comment: There are naming conventions. And i believe javascript follows the same naming conventions as Java does. So to make your code readable for others you better follow them. But as i said "i would", its a suggestions.

Comment: but this has... nothing to do with anything... and at best is a personal opinion not a standard naming convention

Comment: Did you ever hear about code conventions? http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html
This is not my opinion ... Those are best practices. Imagine if there were no conventions how code would look like ... Professionals follow these guidelines.

Comment: but naming conventions and code conventions are not the same thing. well one is a subset of the other, and in this case it is strictly down to the team/developers choice. Once a choice is made the only real concern is to follow it. `var john_smith, marrySmith;` is not cool.

Comment: Ofcourse your code will work and you can write your code however you want to. You can write your own conventions and follow them if that suits you better, but dont you think its smarter to follow the ones that are established and widely used? Because after all its just aesthetics.

Comment: but you are saying all Javascript should use camelCase? Please don't tell me this is what you are saying.

Comment: Im saying we should follow the conventions. And as i can see, most is camelCase, then yes that is my answer. And if you want to get even more dramatic about it, then read what happened in this article with a "convention" problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploration_of_Mars

Answer (score 0):

You got curly quotes in your code

```
alert(“Wrong email”);  <---bad quotes
```

You should not just use a name

```
onsubmit="return validate_form(register);"
```

pass in this which points to the current scope which is the form element.

```
onsubmit="return validate_form(this);"
```

What is EMAIL?

```
EMAIL.value
```

Do not just reference element names.

Comment: sorry. i got it fixed. yet the alert message is still not working